# MATLAB. Secant Method test.

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Test the secant method on an example in which $r$, $f'(r)$ and $f''(r)$ are known in advance. Monitor the ratios $e_{n+1}/(e_n e_{n-1})$ to see whether they converge to $- \frac{1}{2} f"(r) / f'(r)$.

$f(x) = \arctan(x)$ might be a suitable function.

$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$

$f"(x) = -\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JohnLennon: Were you still asking about this? Can it be done without Matlab so you can see what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example
f =inline('sqrt(x)-cos(x)');
p0=1;
p1=2;
for i=0:50
    if abs(p1-p0)<0.000001
        break
    end

```
p=p1-(f(p1)*((p1-p0)/(f(p1)-f(p0))));
p0=p1;
p1=p;
```

F_of_p=f(p);
end
p
F_of_p  %f(p)
i %number of iteration